# Removing non-numeric argument to binary operator Error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am extremely new to R (Day 2). I am putting together a bargraph but am constantly getting the "non-numeric argument to binary operator. Below is all of the code I have written thus far. Any suggestions? I understand that is the (+) error but am unsure of how to correct it and still receive my graph.

I have attempted to remove the `guides(fill=FALSE)` but then I do not get a graph just this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=sumcult5ml, aes(x=reorder(cultivar,eggs5ml, y=eggs5ml)))

geom_bar(aes(fill="sumcult5ml", TRUE),stat="bin", width=.5)

mapping: x = TRUE, fill = sumcult5ml 

geom_bar: width = 0.5, na.rm = FALSE

stat_bin: width = 0.5, na.rm = FALSE

position_stack
```

Code:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=sumcult5ml, aes(x=reorder(cultivar,eggs5ml, y=eggs5ml))) 

geom_bar(aes(fill="sumcult5ml", TRUE),stat="bin", width=.5) + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Error:

```
> plot <- ggplot(data=sumcult5ml, aes(x=reorder(cultivar,eggs5ml, y=eggs5ml)))

> geom_bar(aes(fill="sumcult5ml", TRUE),stat="bin", width=.5) + guides(fill=FALSE)

Error in geom_bar(aes(fill = "sumcult5ml", TRUE), stat = "bin", width = 0.5) +  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thank you for any tips!!

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You missed a closing bracket, and you need to add geoms to the plot. Not run them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Add plot elements with the `+` operator like this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=sumcult5ml, aes(x=reorder(cultivar,eggs5ml, y=eggs5ml))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill="sumcult5ml", TRUE),stat="bin", width=.5) + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Note the `+` at the end of line 1.